# Trying to get property of non-object error in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

ive been trying to match User_id from my users with Creator_id to display the creators username in my post
but im getting the trying to get property from non-object error and i cant get arround it

the function in my controller 
postcontroller.php:

```
public function index()
    {
    $allusers = users::getusers();

    $posts = DB::table('posts')->get();
    foreach ($posts as $posts) {
        foreach ($allusers as $allusers) {
            if ($posts->creator_id == $allusers->user_id) {
              array_push($posts,$allusers->username); 
            }
        }
    }
     return view('blog',['posts'=>$posts]);   
    }
```

the functions in my model:

```
public static function getusers(){
    $allusers = users::all();
    return $allusers;
    }
```

Comment: can you show the output of $posts and $allusers?

Comment: Have you tried to `print_r($posts)` to check what data it holds?

Comment: its not a best way to do to view how create something i suggest you best thing that is save user_id when user create a post and then you can simply get everything from that use_id

Comment: I do not think your usage of `foreach` is correct... I mean the names of variables...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same variable names in your foreach loops :

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    foreach ($allusers as $user) {
        if ($post->creator_id == $user->user_id) {
          array_push($post,$user->username); 
        }
    }
}
```

But for your issue, you should try to add this in your Post Model

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'creator_id', 'user_id);
}
```

then in your view :

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    {{ $post->user->name }}
@endforeach
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse

Comment: aah yes i forgot about the variable names :' ) i read up about the belongsto() method ,works like a charm thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does your users table has a column like user_id?

I think you have check with users table id with posts creator_id.

Comment: why not in 1st loop there is also same name as posts 3 times??